# Gap between status and app bar when pressing back

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

When I load my app, it looks fine as shown:
[image]

However when I tap into a `ListItem` and press the back button, a gap is created as shown:

[image]

Not sure what is causing this:

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/car_nav_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_transport" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

And I am using Android JetPack's Navigation Controller

`nav_transport.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@+id/car_list_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/car_list_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.transportdirectory.fragments.CarListFragment"
        android:label="@string/cars_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_car_list">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_car_list_fragment_to_car_detail_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/car_detail_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/car_detail_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.transportdirectory.fragments.CarDetailFragment"
        android:label="@string/car_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_car_detail">
        <argument
            android:name="vin"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

This is how I invoke the navigation

```
val direction = CarListFragmentDirections.ActionCarListFragmentToCarDetailFragment(vin)
            it.findNavController().navigate(direction)
```

Comment: It could potentially be the close out animation on the back press?  Have you tried overrideExistingTransitions?  I'm not really sure what the desired effect is here.

Comment: what happens when `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"?`